# C++ std::find lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, find, expression

For the life of me, I cannot get this code to work. I'm attempting to convert my code from C# to C++ following the deprecation of the XNA framework, but a stubborn method does not want to be converted. In C# it is:

```
public Tile GetTileAtPosition(bool screenOrGame, Vector2 position)
    {

        if (screenOrGame)
        {
            return Array.Find(tileList, tile => tile.Position == position / 24);
        }
        else
        {
            return Array.Find(tileList, tile => tile.Position == position);
        }
    }
```

In C++, the code I'm attempting to use in place of this is:

```
Tile Level::GetTileAtPosition(bool screenOrGame, sf::Vector2f position)
{
    vector<Tile>::iterator it;

    if (screenOrGame)
    {

        it = find(tileList.begin(), tileList.end(), [position](const Tile &t) { return t.GetPosition() == sf::Vector2f(position.x / 24, position.y / 24); });
        return Tile(it->GetID(), it->GetPosition().x, it->GetPosition().y);

    }

    else
    {

        it = find(tileList.begin(), tileList.end(), [position](const Tile& t) { return t.GetPosition() == position; });
        return Tile(it->GetID(), it->GetPosition().x, it->GetPosition().y);

    }

}
```

On the C++ assignment lines (it = ...) I am getting a painstaking error that I cannot figure out the cause of, or a solution for. It returns:

```
error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Blobby::Level::GetTileAtPosition::<lambda_29eb981cd341d9c05d39c4654bc470b9>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 3186
```

Is there any way to fix this error, or a better/more practical way to implement the method in C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++, the versions taking a comparator are sometimes suffixed with `_if`. This is the case for `std::find`. `std::find` takes an element to find, whereas `std::find_if` takes a comparator that implements equality. The error simply means that it couldn't find a match for a `Tile` being equivalent to a lambda.